# Tradingview Lightweight Charts priceline length

Tags: tradingview-api

Can create pricelines on my chart, but I want the pricelines to be only a length of a couple of candles instead of filling the whole chart. Did not find anything in the documentation but workarounds are highly appreciated.

```
        const myPriceLine = {
            price: 4814.43,
            color: '#000000',
            lineWidth: 1,
            lineStyle: 1,
            axisLabelVisible: true,
            title: 'All Time High',
        };        

        candlestickSeries.createPriceLine(myPriceLine);
```